# Logical operations in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Assume two  `Mat CV_8UC1` images, `mask`, and `label`, how to do the following operation in OpenCV (C++):

```
mask(label==5) = 255; // this is allowed in Matlab 

// or 

mask[label==5] = 255; // this is allowed in Python
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`inrange()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981) with `lowerb` and `upperb` both set to `5`,

or you could use [`compare()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga303cfb72acf8cbb36d884650c09a3a97) with `src2` set to `5` and `cmpop` set to `cv::CMP_EQ`.

Both will set the output mask to be 255 where the values match.

Answer (score 3):

It's literally just...

```cpp
mask.setTo(255, label == 5);
```

Second argument is the `mask` argument.